# Changing iframe to relative location when parent is in another path

Tags: javascript, html, http, browser

I have the following pages on same domain:

- /A/p1.html
- /B/p2.html
- /B/p3.html

p1.html contains an IFRAME showing p2.html. p2.html can also run alone (as a top-level document). Eventually, p2.html runs the following JavaScript statement:

```
document.location.href = 'p3.html';
```

If p2.html is a top-level document, it works fine. Chrome sends the user to /B/p3.html.

Now if p2.html is an IFRAME inside p1.html, then Chrome sends the IFRAME to /A/p3.html, giving a 404 error. I want Chrome to put IFRAME on /B/p3.html, since p2.html is already on /B/.

How can I make relative URLs work both from inside an IFRAME and also as a top-level document?

Comment: And what's wrong with `document.location.href = '/B/p3.html';`?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 The same page can be deployed to different paths. The /B/ pages are designed to work on wherever they were deployed, not just /B/. This was working just fine until somebody decided to put my pages on an IFRAME.

Comment: Ouch, I understand the oddity of changing requests, etc.

Comment: document.location should be window.location by the way

Comment: @mplungjan Tried window.location, same problem.

Comment: I know, that is not your issue. Your issue is to point the location.href to the path of the parent. like `location=parent.location.pathname.split("/")[0]+"/p3.html"`

Comment: @mplungjan his issue is that the path of the parent !== path of iframe.

Comment: @mplungjan No, that's no my issue either. I want setting href to have same effect of clicking a link. By the way, if I click on a link href="p3.html", the IFRAME goes to /B/p3.html.

Comment: @fernacolo, can you `console.log(document.location.href)` inside p2.html and post the results?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 After some investigation I found that it happens only when the action is triggered by some script on p1.html. Since it works on FF, I filled a bug for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This works on FireFox, so it's definetly a Chrome bug. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357988